# T/SQL - QUERY for duplicate with a twist

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL Code that I have worked on so far.

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (ID INT Identity (1,1), Col1 varchar(50), Col2 varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @Table1 (Col1, Col2)
VALUES ('CAN','ABCD'),('CAN','ABCE'),('CAN','MNPP'),('CAN','MNPP'),('EDG','MNPP')

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (ID INT Identity (1,1), Col2 varchar(50), Col3 varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @Table2 (Col2, Col3)
VALUES ('ABCD','ABC'),('ABCE','ABC'),('MNPP','MNO')

;WITH TEST_CTE AS
(
SELECT T1.ID
       , T1.Col1, T1.Col2 AS T1Col2, T2.Col2 AS T2Col2, T2.Col3
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.Col1, T2.Col3 ORDER BY T1.ID) AS DuplicateRowNumber
       , CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY T1.Col1, T2.Col3) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END IsMulitple
 FROM @Table1 T1 INNER JOIN @Table2 T2 ON T1.Col2 = T2.Col2
)

SELECT * FROM TEST_CTE
```

I am getting

```
ID  Col1    T1Col2  T2Col2  Col3    DuplicateRowNumber  IsMulitple
1   CAN     ABCD    ABCD    ABC     1                   1
2   CAN     ABCE    ABCE    ABC     2                   1
3   CAN     MNPP    MNPP    MNO     1                   1
4   CAN     MNPP    MNPP    MNO     2                   1
5   EDG     MNPP    MNPP    MNO     1                   0
```

I am expecting

```
ID  Col1    T1Col2  T2Col2  Col3    DuplicateRowNumber  IsMulitple
1   CAN     ABCD    ABCD    ABC     1                   1
2   CAN     ABCE    ABCE    ABC     2                   1
3   CAN     MNPP    MNPP    MNO     1                   0
4   CAN     MNPP    MNPP    MNO     1                   0
5   EDG     MNPP    MNPP    MNO     1                   0
```

My Goal: 
My duplicate should only be queried when I have multiple records where T1.Col1 and T2.Col3 values are same BUT T1.Col2 values are different.

Thank you

UPDATE: Got IsMultiple to work. Not able to figure out DuplicateRowNumber

UPDATE 2: nvm that previous update, doesn't work very well with live data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
;with cte as
(
select t1.id, t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col3, dense_rank() over(partition by t1.col1, t2.col3 order by t1.col2) DuplicateRowNumber
from @table1 t1 
join @table2 t2 on t1.col2 = t2.col2
)
select *, sign(max(DuplicateRowNumber) over (partition by col1, col3)-1) Ismultiple
from cte
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aef9d/2/0)

Comment: Umm...this is great!!! Thanks! Just confused at the outer Select query. Can you please explain the logic behind this?

Comment: max of duplicate is 1 if there is 1 row, more if there are more rows. Subtract 1 and take the *sign* value, with *sign 0* is 0 and a positive value is 1 (negative value returns -1)